# panto и drag в google map js V3

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

Проблема такая:

Кручу карту с мобильного устройства . По сути выполняю dragging.

1. делаю сильный свайп по карте, чтобы карта долго "катилась" в направлении свайпа.
2. В этот момент вызываю panto(lat, lng). Карта резко подскакивает в нужные мне координаты, но потом так же резко улетает в продолжение моего свайпа, и останавливается уже там.

Как итог. Мой panTo сработал, но его перетер dragging.

Видимо нужно до вызова panTo вызывать принудительный стоп драгинга. А как это сделать я не знаю. Помогите